# External monitor shuts off when set as only monitor

Tags: laptop, external-display, asus-laptop

So I've got an ASUS PB287Q hooked up to my Asus NV550JV through DisplayPort. I'm running Windows 8.1 and my problem is the following:

If I extend my desktop from the laptop, then everything is fine.
If I mirror my desktop from the laptop, then everything is fine.
If I choose output to go to the external monitor, then it powers off and refuses to show anything. My laptop keeps running.

I didn't have this problem with a Dell monitor hooked up through HDMI.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Windows has taken it on itself to try and drive the monitor at an unsupported rate when it is the only output. I think that is going to be very hard to fix though.

I did note that quite a few people have had refresh rate problems (stuck at 30MHz instead of 60) so I wonder if that is related? Have you tried changing the settings on the monitor? Does you laptop support DP 1.2? Is the monitor set to the same DP version as the laptop supports?

I assume you've tried HDMI as well?

Comment: Monitor is set to dp 1.2. How do I find out about the laptop? Monitor us at 60 fps

Comment: Not sure, the ASUS web site? Can't see anything with a quick look, I did check. Maybe try setting the monitor back to 1.1? and try HDMI? Also, what graphics card does the laptop have? Can it drive the full 4k?

Comment: For desktop usage it can, gaming it can't. Nvidia GT 750M. Setting it to 1.1 fixed it, but 30 fps isn't acceptable, any thoughts on a fix.

Comment: Try forcing to a lower but supported resolution while on 1.1 then change back to 1.2 - see if that works.